# Meaning of PF_VCPU and PF_WQ_WORKER

Tags: process, scheduling

do you know what the constants meaning is defined in `linux/sched.h`:

```
  #define PF_VCPU       0x00000010  /* I'm a virtual CPU */
  #define PF_WQ_WORKER  0x00000020  /* I'm a workqueue worker */
```

What does it mean when a process have both flags set (the ninth parameter in `/proc/[pid]/stat` is `0x30` or decimal `48`)

I only found that short comments after the define's but i can not imagine any sense.

Answer (score 1):

This bit explains the purpose of `PF_WQ_WORKER`.

*excerpt*

> Concurrency managed workqueue needs to know when workers are going to
>   sleep and waking up, and, when a worker goes to sleep, be able to wake
>   up another worker to maintain adequate concurrency. This patch
>   introduces `PF_WQ_WORKER` to identify workqueue workers and adds the
>   following two hooks.
>
> - `wq_worker_waking_up()`: called when a worker is woken up.
> - `wq_worker_sleeping()`: called when a worker is going to sleep and may
>     return a pointer to a local task which should be woken up. The
>     returned task is woken up using `try_to_wake_up_local()` which is
>     simplified `ttwu` which is called under `rq lock` and can only wake up
>     local tasks.
>
> Both hooks are currently defined as `noop` in `kernel/workqueue_sched.h`.
>   Later `cmwq` implementation will replace them with proper
>   implementation.
>
> These hooks are hard coded as they'll always be enabled.

***Source:*** [[PATCH 4/4] sched: add hooks for workqueue](http://www.serverphorums.com/read.php?12,146713)

Comment: Searching found nothing on the PF_VCPU bit.

Answer (score 1):

The [`PF_VCPU`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=3.14;i=PF_VCPU) flag is set in [`guest_enter`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/context_tracking.h?v=3.14#L80) which is called by [`kvm_guest_enter`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/kvm_host.h?v=3.14#L783) which is called in [`kvm_arch_vcpu_ioctl_run`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kvm/arm.c?v=3.14#L577). As far as I understand, it's an annotation on a process that's running inside a KVM virtual machine; as far as the host scheduler is concerned, the process is active in the guise of its virtual machine. It was [introduced](http://lkml.iu.edu//hypermail/linux/kernel/0708.2/0513.html) to properly track spent in a process running inside a VM vs time spent by the VM itself.